# How do I access a user password on a Mac?

Tags: mac, passwords

A teacher of mine recently told me that the admin password on Macs at my high school has not been obtained by a student in twelve years, so, naturally I took that as a challenge. Is there any way to obtain this password? I couldn't find an unencrypted version of it in the system files. I even filmed someone typing the password into a computer and tried to identify it by looking at the pressed keys. This didn't work. I tried programming a python keystroke logger, but it didn't work for the admin password prompts. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Let me get this right. You want someone on this site to tell you, and anyone else who Googles in here, how to crack a Mac user password? Don't you think it might be, well, kind of against policy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forgot Password on Mac iBook](https://superuser.com/questions/26916/forgot-password-on-mac-ibook)

Comment: At least in that one the questioner says 'I forgot it', this one says 'I want to crack my school's Macs'.

Comment: It depends on the version of Mac OS.  If it's something older, check out this answer on the Apple stack: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186893/os-x-10-9-where-are-password-hashes-stored

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need the password of an existing admin account if you want admin access to a Mac you have physical access to. If the Mac does not have a firmware password enabled, you can boot it while holding down Cmd-S to boot into single-user mode, which gives you a root shell. Then you can follow the on-screen instructions to check the boot drive and remount it read/write, and then `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` and then `reboot`. When it reboots, the first-boot Setup Assistant will be run again, and you can use it to create another account with admin access.

This will let you do just about anything on the system, but without knowing the original admin account's password, you won't be able to unlock that account's user keychain and potentially learn other passwords that might be stored there.